# Validate Node Before Saving With EntityMetadataWrapper?

Tags: entities

I am creating nodes with EntityMetadataWrapper that need to be checked with the unique_field module. I noticed that duplicate nodes are being saved because EMW doesn't validate the node before saving as mentioned here:

https://drupal.org/node/643972

How can I enforce my unique_field settings for this node when creating and saving with EntityMetadataWrapper?